# Java 8 JavaDoc generation fails with IllegalArgumentException when it reaches constant value

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javadoc

In my Java Maven project I'm using Java 8 JDK (v1.8.0_112), Maven 3 and maven-javadoc-plugin v2.10.4.

My code is the following (reduced):

```
public class DummyData {

    public static final String USE_CURSOR = "&useCursor";

    // fields, constructor, methods omitted...

}
```

While generating class JavaDoc uing Maven goal, the following error appears

```
1 error
[ERROR] MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: 
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "&useCursor"

Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\..\bin\javadoc.exe" @options @packages

Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\Users\xan\git\Demo\demo\target\apidocs' dir.

org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: 
Exit code: 1 - javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "&useCursor"
```

Do you know why is this an issue?
My best guess is the '&' character which confuses JavaDoc but don't know how to do alternative (without changing the constant)?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the Javadoc comment?

Comment: Actually, that is the most confusing part. There is no comment... This constant confuses the JavaDoc generator...

Comment: What can an automatic generator do for Javadocs but repeat the declaration? How can that be useful? Write the darn Javadoc comment yourself, for Pete's sake.

Comment: Still the same issue after adding JavaDoc (/** Use cursor doc. */) directly above the constant... I'll try new Java Version...

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the reported error, I found some results that point to a same problem.

[Eclipse JavaDoc Generation fails with IllegalArgumentException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183675/eclipse-javadoc-generation-fails-with-illegalargumentexception)

[Javadoc creation failes with IlegalArgumentExpection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636215/javadoc-creation-failes-with-ilegalargumentexpection)

According to these posts, it can be an issue with the `CLASSPATH` variable. Since you are using Eclipse, building and generating javadoc does not require further configuration outside the IDE.

The suggested solution is to clear the CLASSPATH variable (`set classpath=`). Hope it helps solve the problem.

Comment: I'm actually using IntelliJ Idea

Comment: for linux:  `export CLASSPATH=`